# Continuous Build Tools: can I accommodate many of them if I create a Jar?

Tags: build-process, build-automation

I have a tool that checks code for security flaws. The tool has an open restful API and I would like to be able to accommodate continuous integration tools out there. The idea being that assuming someone uses a Jenkins, Ant, Maven, Apache Gump, CruiseControl,etc they could insert and trigger the execution of the tool within the process somewhere.

I created a .Jar file that takes a few command line parameters and upon execution will start the tool. I was hoping that launching a Jar be flexible enough to be able to be used by many of these different software build programs.

I'm noticing things like Jenkins and Maven have their own plugin systems but for maintainability I'd prefer not to need to create plugins based on each technology. Do you think having a launch able Jar be a possible more independent option?

I can see that ANT has the ability to launch a Jar I'm just not sure it be doable for others?

There a better way I might be overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

Throw in a shell, batch script to invoke the jar and you should be fine as far as CI tools go. If your jar launches a server, be sure to provide a startup and shoutdown script that exit with code 0 on success and non-zero otherwise.